# clone with onclick handler with args

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

i am cloning an element and that element will have a onclick handler. That event handler will send as argument an ID.
My problem is when i click on the element, he sends the last ID of the cicle for.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function cloneActions(idRoutine){ //clone elements 
    var actionDiv = document.getElementById("actionsImages-"+idRoutine).getElementsByClassName("actionImage"); //parent with content that must be cloned
    var allActions = document.getElementById("actions"); //parent div
    while (allActions.firstChild) { //remove all existing imgs
         allActions.removeChild(allActions.firstChild);
    }
    for(var i=0; i < actionDiv.length; i++){ //set all images and handlers
       var image = actionDiv[i].cloneNode(true);
       var id = image.id;
       image.onclick = function() { selectAction(id);};
       allActions.appendChild(image);
    }       
}
function selectAction(id){ //handler function
    ///jquery
}
```

And the html code:

```
<div id="actionsImages-«id»" class="tile__list actionsImages">
    <img src='sortable/st/foo.jpg' class='actionImage' id=«id» title='foo'/>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your lesson in `for` loops, variable hoisting, and asynchronous events in javascript. Don't worry, we all go through this lesson. Here goes:

Here's your `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < actionDiv.length; i++) {
   var image = actionDiv[i].cloneNode(true);
   var id = image.id;
   image.onclick = function() { selectAction(id);};
   allActions.appendChild(image);
}
```

This is the same as doing this:

```
var image;
var id;
for(var i=0; i < actionDiv.length; i++) {
   image = actionDiv[i].cloneNode(true);
   id = image.id;
   image.onclick = function() { selectAction(id);};
   allActions.appendChild(image);
}
```

This is because [variables in javascript are hoisted to the the top of their scope](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) during run time. What this means is that your `for` loop runs, your variables `image` and `id` are set to a new value on every iteration of the loop, and when the loop is done, the variables are holding the value **of the last iteration of your loop**.

(read that last part in bold again)

Then, some time in the future, your user clicks on the image, and your click handler calls the function `selectAction` and passes the `id`. Well, if you read that text in **bold** once again, your `id` variable is going to be holding the **value from the last iteration of your `for` loop**.

(read that last part in bold again)

To illustrate the problem, lets strip it down to the bare bones. Copy this code into your console:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var someVar = i;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("The value of 'someVar' is " + someVar);
    }, i * 300);
}
```

See how `someVar` is equal to 4 every time. This is the crux of your problem.

To fix your problem, you can you use the "bind" function like this:

```
var image, id, i;
for(i=0; i < actionDiv.length; i++) {
   image = actionDiv[i].cloneNode(true);
   id = image.id;
   image.onclick = selectAction.bind(image, id)
   allActions.appendChild(image);
}
```

I'll let you read about how function binding works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Another solution is to have a function that you call inside your `for` loop:

```
function doCoolStuff (i) {
   var image = actionDiv[i].cloneNode(true);
   var id = image.id;
   image.onclick = function () { selectAction(id); };
   allActions.appendChild(image);
}

for(var i=0; i < actionDiv.length; i++) {
   doCoolStuff(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks! im newbie with javascript as you can see :) i used bind method. to the record, i just have to edit my code in selectAction() because id is the full handler and now i have to get the id by calling «id.target.id»

Comment: Doh, I misused the `bind` method [bangs head on table]. I have fixed my code - try it now.

Comment: This is a good lesson - I hope it makes sense to you what's going on. The `bind` method will save you, as will `call` and `apply`. They are all similar but fundamentally different and useful. I recommend reading about them until you understand it like second nature.